# What are the two tubes connected to my refrigerator?

Tags: plumbing

I bought a used whirlpool refrigerator, I don't know if something is missing or what. There are two plastic tubing lines coming out of the back of the refrigerator. Now I know one needs to connect to the in flowing water tube from the wall. But I cannot figure out why the second one is there and what it needs to connect to.  I hooked the gray to the main water source. But, when I turn the water on the The clear line seaped water when the pressure started to mount . Where should that clearline be hooked to?   Please help

Comment: Look up the model number of the fridge on the internet and you should find the manual.  It should detail in the manual how to connect the tubes.

Comment: Maybe a hot water line? Or a drain? Or a previous owner rigged up the second line to run water to another appliance?

Comment: Most likely the second tube is a drip tray drain line.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the tubing is reversed, there is a valve that will hold pressure from one direction only. I have never seen gray line connected to main supply. 
There really is no Hot water connection to a refrigerator. Although hot water will freeze faster than ambient, that would defeat the purpose of a refrigerator, by pumping in hot water. Besides the water doesn't stay on long enough for it to work well. The gray line most likely goes in a tray under your fridge. The drain from the in door water tray has to go somewhere. So I have seen them in a tray so that the heat from the compressor and fans will evaporate the wasted water and melting ice cubes.